# how to access parent window javascript variable inside child window(pop-up)?

Tags: javascript

I have html page which has global javascript variable with name `custName="scott"`. I open the pop-up window with `window.open`.

Now if I access the `custName` inside pop-up window with `window.opener.custName`, I get values as `undefined`. How do I access parent window javascript variable inside child window(pop-up)?

Comment: window.opener should do it, can you provide an URL or fiddle?

Comment: Use javaScript Query String  try this it may help u (https://github.com/sousk/jquery.parsequery#readme)

Comment: Try window.parent http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp

Comment: Is the variable declared as a global? For example... `window.custName = "scott";`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`window.opener.custName` works. It was typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the Query string in javaScript

```
link.html?page=1

<script type="text/javascript">

        $.getUrlVar('page');
        $.extend({
              getUrlVars: function(){
              var vars = [], hash;
              var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&amp;');
              for(var i = 0; i &lt; hashes.length; i++)
              {
                   hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                   vars.push(hash[0]);
                   vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
             }
             return vars;
        },
       getUrlVar: function(name){
           return $.getUrlVars()[name];
       }
 });

</script>
```