# Send javascript array to the new window when using window.open

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to send array from the current page to the page opened when using window.open function, is it possible? and how to achieve this?

Comment: Show some code what you have done or trying to do

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941504/how-to-access-parent-window-javascript-variable-inside-child-windowpop-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep a reference to the opened window you can communicate with it.

```
var mywin = window.open(...); 
mywin.somearray = [1,2,3];
```

There's a catch, however: it may not work if the pop-up was blocked by the browser, then allowed by the user clicking a "allow" button. It may be a better idea to go the other way around and reference `window.opener.somearray` from within the pop-up.

Comment: How to receive it in the opened page with javascript??

Comment: it's accessible in the child window's global scope as `somearray`.

Comment: Does IE 11 support this method??

Comment: Yes, it does. It's been in web browsers since forever ;)

Comment: When using somearray in the opend page, it works fine for me in firefox and chrome, but in IE said, somearray is undefined, any idea?

Comment: Please help me, I have to get this working!

Comment: Read my edited answer. I think getting `somearray` from the `window.opener` will be just as easy and probably more bulletproof.

Comment: I tried to use your edited ansower, but didn't work on all of them, maybe I didn't understand how to use it correctly, I defined a variable in the parent page 
     var test="test";
and in the popup page I tried to use it like this:
     window.opener.test 
but didn't give anything!

Answer (score 1):

serialize your array. and pass it in window.open url parameter.In the opened page unseralize the string to array and use it.